# Caching and DigitalOcean - anyone experienced with this?

Tags: caching, hosting, digital-ocean

Does DigitalOcean do any caching by default?

We are hosting a Membership that requires a bunch of **NON-caching** to take place...

Or, said another way, is the caching done by DigitalOcean - or - is it done by a 3rd party plugin like WP Rocket on our own site? We are using ServerPilot too...

Here are the strict specs we need to ensure: https://docs.memberpress.com/article/72-what-web-hosting-works-best-with-memberpress

I appreciate all the feedback.